# Why does this code outputs two different results?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a function that returns the length of an array, but the function always returns 8

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int size(int arr[])
{
    return sizeof(arr);
}

int main()
{
    int v[] = {1, 2, 4};
    cout << sizeof(v) << endl;
    cout << size(v);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The parameter `arr` in your `size()` function is a pointer, not the array. It is 8 bytes on a 64bit system. Want to pass an array by value? Use `std::array`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because ‘sizeof’ on array function parameter ‘arr’ will return size of ‘int*’..